# Comparing dates in Javascript without Timezones

Tags: javascript, date

I'm attempting to get the date based on user's local settings, subtract a day from it and then compare the value with another date value that I'm putting it. 
I have tried it with moment.js and even date object of Javascript, using getTime() and then comparing the two dates, but none of them worked for me. 
isSame was working when I tested it earlier, but for some reason it isn't working anymore. FYI the date I'm comparing it with(activityDate), I take it from a uploaded xlsx sheet using a upload widget. I need the comparison be timezone independent as user's locale can be anything. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the code snippet:

```
var currentBusinessDate = new Date();
var previousBusinessDate = moment(currentBusinessDate).subtract(1, 'days').toDate();
var previousDate = $scope.getDateCellValueStr(previousBusinessDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'); //Output: "13-11-2017"

if (moment(activityDate).isSame(previousDate, 'day')) {
                        uploadData.push(temp);
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
```

//activityDate: "13-11-2017"
//Result: condition returns False

Comment: check `currentBusinessDate.getTime()== previousBusinessDate.getTime()`

Comment: If you can use external libraries, I reocmmend you to take a look to `momentjs`: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have to compare activity date with previous date, and check that they be same.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I have used moment.js, didn't work.

Comment: how do you know the value of activityDate and the other one? have you used alert();? Also, check previousDate type, if it is not moment, then it compares to null

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be using setUTCHours: all the dates are going to be set to the same timezone (UTC) and then you will be able to compare them.

```
const compareWithoutTimezone(date1, date2) => {
   const date1UTC = date1.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   const date2UTC = date2.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   return date1UTC === date2UTC;
}
```